# VBS MoveFile Issue

Tags: file-io, vbscript

I did write the 1st if statement and it worked well in start while my file sizes were just in kbs.

as my file sizes got to mbs it started giving me problems like it was not renaming the file to .CSV again from .CSV.tmp hence I decided to add File Size before and after(2nd IF statement) , But it started to show me 2 debug msgBox "Entry in B Request with File : " and then "fname". after that it fails and don't give and error but don't do the job too.

do you find any issues with it?

```
Option Explicit
Dim FSO, FLD, FIL, GetFileSize1, GetFileSize2, f, fname
Dim strFolder,strFileName

strFolder = "\Sieb\Request"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

For Each Fil In FLD.Files
  strFileName=Lcase(Fil.Name)

  If instr (1,strFileName,"_a_request_")>0 then
    if (FSO.FileExists(".\Sieb_Process_Files\a\Request\"+Fil.Name)) then
    else
      FSO.MoveFile ".\Request\"+Fil.Name,".\Sieb_Process_Files\a\Request\" + Fil.Name +".tmp"
      FSO.MoveFile ".\Sieb_Process_Files\a\Request\" + Fil.Name +".tmp", ".\Sieb_Process_Files\a\Request\" + Fil.Name 
    end if
  End if

  If instr (1,strFileName,"_b_request_")>0 then
    if (FSO.FileExists(".\Sieb_Process_Files\b\Request\"+Fil.Name)) then
    else
      MsgBox "Entry in B Request with File : " + Fil.Name
      set fname = ".\Sieb_Process_Files\b\Request\" + Fil.Name
      MsgBox fname
      set f = FSO.GetFile(fname) 
      GetFileSize1 = f.size 
      MsgBox "Orignal File Size" + GetFileSize1
      FSO.MoveFile ".\Request\"+Fil.Name,".\Sieb_Process_Files\b\Request\" + Fil.Name +".tmp"
      set f = FSO.GetFile(".\Sieb_Process_Files\b\Request\" + Fil.Name +".tmp") 
      GetFileSize2 = f.size 
      MsgBox "Copied File Size" + GetFileSize2
      MsgBox "File Moved with tmp name"
      Do Until GetFileSize1=GetFileSize2
        FSO.MoveFile ".\Sieb_Process_Files\b\Request\" + Fil.Name +".tmp" ,".\Sieb_Process_Files\b\Request\" + Fil.Name 
        MsgBox "File renamed to orignal name exiting now"
        Exit Do
      Loop
    end if
  End if
Next
Set Fil = nothing
set FSO = nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly not possible that your first `If` conditional ever successfully moved a file that didn't exist in the destination (and file size doesn't have anything to do with it).

```
if (FSO.FileExists(".\Sieb_Process_Files\a\Request\"+Fil.Name)) then
else
  FSO.MoveFile ".\Request\"+Fil.Name,".\Sieb_Process_Files\a\Request\" + Fil.Name +".tmp"
  FSO.MoveFile ".\Sieb_Process_Files\a\Request\" + Fil.Name +".tmp", ".\Sieb_Process_Files\a\Request\" + Fil.Name 
end if
```

Once you move the file to a different location/name the file your variable `Fil` refers to doesn't exist anymore, so the second `MoveFile` (or rather, the attempt to access the property `Fil.Name`) would raise a "File not Found" error. If you didn't get an error you have an `On Error Resume Next` in your code that you didn't show.

Also, why are you moving the file to a temp name and then back to the original name in the same directory? That would only make sense when moving the file to a hot folder on a different volume, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Something like this should be all you need:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso, sourceFolder, targetFolder, f, target

sourceFolder = "\Sieb\Request"
targetFolder = ".\Sieb_Process_Files\a\Request"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(sourceFolder).Files
  target = fso.BuildPath(targetFolder, f.Name)

  If InStr(1, f.Name, "_a_request_", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    If Not fso.FileExists(target) Then
      f.Move target
    End If
  End If
Next
```

`vbTextCompare` makes `InStr()` comparisons case-insensitive, so you don't need to lowercase the filename.

Comment: _italic_Once you move the file to a different location/name the file your variable Fil refers to doesn't exist anymore, so the second MoveFile (or rather, the attempt to access the property Fil.Name) would raise a "File not Found" error. _italic_

Point is perfectly valid.

BTW

Comment: _italic_"File not Found" error. _italic_

**bold** Point is perfectly valid, my script started working after replacing the fil.Name by another variable **bold** 

_italic_On Error Resume Next._italic_ 
**bold** I did paste entire script I did not use OnError Resume Next **bold**  


_italic_ Also, why are you moving the file to a temp name and then back to the original name in the same directory?  _italic_

Comment: **Its hot holder another exe picks up the files before it get complete transfer as files size are big and on Source and destination are two diff servers which takes more time to transfer. ** 
  
your code I dint tried to use as mine suits to my needs perfectly just 1 change as you suggested :) thanks !